# How to adjust a custom mouse cursors click position in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse, cursor, mouse-cursor

I made a custom mouse cursor (a simple semi-transparent circle to look like a touch position instead of a cursor), and set windows to use it by selecting it in the mouse settings, however the position that the click happens is incorrect (it's the bottom left corner of the custom mouse cursor image).

I would like set this to be the centre of the circle.  Is there a way do specific an offset x and y?

Comment: You have to edit the .cur file to specify the hotspot. [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)). I imagine the various freeware editors offer this capability.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @KeithMiller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using https://www.cursor.cc which lets you set the hotspot, works perfectly now thanks.